# Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, npm, path

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.0
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Node.js v18.16.0

This is showing the wrong path for some reason and I'm not able to change it. How do I change it?

Comment: What command are you running that causes this behavior? Have you tried reinstalling node?

Comment: Yes, I have reinstalled several times. I'm running the normal npm command.  The problem is in the path Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'. After entering into the bin it's repeating node_modules\npm\bin\npm for some reason.

Comment: What does your path look like? Run `path` in a command prompt. if it's too long for a comment maybe use pastebin.com or add it to your original post.